# New docker Image from Running container doesnt hold updated values

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-container

I have used Jenkins docker image from dockerhub(https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker)

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
ENV http_proxy http://bc-proxy-vip.de.pri.o2.com:8080
ENV https_proxy http://bc-proxy-vip.de.pri.o2.com:8080
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ldap-utils curl wget vim nano sudo
RUN adduser jenkins sudo
User jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 50000
```

The docker build command was executed successfully and container also started successfully.

Docker build command :

```
docker build --no-cache -t myjenkins .
```

Docker container command :

```
docker run --net=host --name=my_jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 myjenkins
```

Then I logged into Jenkins GUI , created a new user and updated the plugins.

Then created a new image using `docker commit` command. Master Image ID is c068f8d9a060. The newly created docker image ID is de0789b77703

```
docker commit c052fd7a26b3 almjenkins:version1
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:~/jenkins# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
almjenkins          version1            de0789b77703        13 minutes ago      1.04GB
myjenkins           latest              c068f8d9a060        4 hours ago         1.03GB
```

I executed docker run command to start the Jenkins from my new image.

```
docker run --net=host --name=alm_jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 almjenkins:version1
```

When i accessed the Jenkins GUI, I'm unable to find the updates in new image.

Comment: Docker will not commit changes made to a volume, you need to externally persist data from a docker volume

Comment: I have updated my plugins, configured proxy details in plugin manager. How to retrieve these updates and update it in new image.

Comment: You can use `docker cp` to get out the data from `/var/jenkins_home`, from your existing container

Answer (score 0):

As descibed in the offical docs for [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/):

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.

The `jenkins_home` which holds all the jenkins configuration is declared as a volume in the Dockerfile for jenkins. Thus the commit command won't inlude can configuration (jobs, nodes, plugins ...)

The solution is to build a customized docker image that includes the configuration.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

COPY jobs /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh workflow-aggregator:2.5 ... # Install all the plugins that you need
```

You can extract the jobs folder from the old container and add it to the new on:

```
docker cp <container-name>:/var/jenkins_home/jobs jobs
```

Comment: In my case, I have created a Jenkins docker image and done all the plugin updates ,created job,ldap security settings and this jenkin container act as primary server. Now I need to create one more Jenkins docker from updated one. Do I need to copy all the Jenkins related files from Docker volume to HOST volume

Comment: @user2439278 For jobs just copy the jobs folder under `/var/jenkins_home/jobs` and put it in the new image. For the plugins I suggest you put the version needed inside the Dockerfile and rebuild the image.

Comment: to rebuild a Image, I need to write a Dockerfile which contains name of the new docker image and customize the image. What about LDAP security setting implemented in Jenkins primary container. How can I achieve? I need an exact copy of running container as a new image. Can i proceed with Docker save command

Comment: You can copy the whole jenkins_home from the old container and put it in the new image. This will effectively give you an identical container to the old one. Alternatively, for LDAP stuff you can configure it using an init script that will execute once the container is started; you can create an `LDAPSecurityRealm` and set it on the Jenkins instance. If you have a 
lot of configuration, simply copying the jenkins_home to the new image should be enough.